# Recursive SELECT in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

Table One

```
NumLig - CodPro - CodDer
901 - BSFX30 - 0140I18
898 - RSFX30 - 18
6 - MFLX - U
```

Table Two

```
NumLig - CodCmp - DerCmp - QtdUti - PerCmp
6 - MDFIB0008 - null - 1 - 2
6 - MDQDN0009 - null - 0,24 - 1
898 - MFLX - U - 0,942 - 2
898 - MDCAM0002 - 0,05 - 0
901 - RSFX - 18 - 1 - 2,5
901 - EDEAD0005 - 0,245 - 0
```

What I need is that I search for BSFX30 - 0140I18 the output to be:

```
MDFIB0008 - null - 1 - 2
MDQDN0009 - null - 0,24 - 1
MFLX - U - 0,942 - 2
MDCAM0002 - 0,05 - 0
RSFX - 18 - 1 - 2,5
EDEAD0005 - 0,245 - 0
```

If I do this:

```
SELECT E622SIM.CodPro, E622SIM.CodDer, E622DER.TipCpc, E622SIM.NumLig, E622DER.CodCmp, E622DER.DerCmp, E622DER.QtdUti, E622DER.PerCmp
FROM E622SIM
JOIN E622DER
ON E622SIM.NumLig = E622DER.NumLig
```

The output to be all the data, but I need filter by CodPro and CodDer. If I do this:

```
SELECT E622SIM.CodPro, E622SIM.CodDer, E622DER.TipCpc, E622SIM.NumLig, E622DER.CodCmp, E622DER.DerCmp, E622DER.QtdUti, E622DER.PerCmp
FROM E622SIM
JOIN E622DER
ON E622SIM.NumLig = E622DER.NumLig
```

the output to be only:

```
RSFX - 18 - 1 - 2,5
EDEAD0005 - 0,245 - 0
```

but I need:

```
MDFIB0008 - null - 1 - 2
MDQDN0009 - null - 0,24 - 1
MFLX - U - 0,942 - 2
MDCAM0002 - 0,05 - 0
RSFX - 18 - 1 - 2,5
EDEAD0005 - 0,245 - 0
```

This because RSFX is children of BSFX30, and MFLX is children of RSFX

Thanks!

Comment: You gave us nothing to work with. We see the data, yes. We don't see the relationships between them.

Comment: select CodCmp, DerCmp, QtdUti, PerCmp from table_two;

Comment: What is "recursive" about this? Please edit your question and add further details about what you're trying to accomplish. Also, please post the code you've already written. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the question to try to explain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need see documentation about [Hierarchical Queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)
to connect your data use `connect by`, to get root element - `connect_by_root`, to filter the elements by root you need use `where connect_by_root(E622SIM.CodPro)  = 'BSFX30'`

I tried to compile your description into scripts

```
create table E622SIM(NumLig int, CodPro varchar2(100), CodDer varchar2(100));

insert into E622SIM values (901, 'BSFX30', '0140I18');
insert into E622SIM values (898, 'RSFX30', '18');
insert into E622SIM values (6, 'MFLX', 'U');

create table E622DER (NumLig int, CodCmp varchar2(100), DerCmp varchar2(100), QtdUti varchar2(100), PerCmp varchar2(100));
insert into E622DER values(901, 'RSFX30',18,1,'2,5');
insert into E622DER values(901, 'EDEAD0005',0,245,0);
insert into E622DER values(898, 'MFLX','U','0,942',2);
insert into E622DER values(898, 'MDCAM0002',null,'0,05',0);
insert into E622DER values(6, 'MDFIB0008', null, 1, 2);
insert into E622DER values(6, 'MDQDN0009',null,'0,24',1);
```

and this is the query that looks as what you need

```
select E622DER.CodCmp
      ,E622DER.DerCmp
      ,E622DER.QtdUti
      ,E622DER.PerCmp
from E622DER
  left outer join E622SIM on E622SIM.NumLig = E622DER.NumLig
  where connect_by_root(E622SIM.CodPro)  in ('BSFX30')
   connect by prior E622DER.CodCmp = E622SIM.CodPro  
order by level desc, E622DER.CodCmp asc

    CODCMP  DERCMP  QTDUTI  PERCMP
1   MDFIB0008       1   2
2   MDQDN0009       0,24    1
3   MDCAM0002       0,05    0
4   MFLX    U   0,942   2
5   EDEAD0005   0   245 0
6   RSFX30  18  1   2,5
```